# How do I resolve connectivity errors in Azure Video Analyzer for Media?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I'm using Azure Video Analyzer for Media.
When using it, the following error message is always displayed.
"There was a problem connecting to Azure Media Service."
[image]

After entering the information specified in Settings, the dialog message displayed "The connection to Azure Media Service was successfully updated."
(The value required for the connection information is obtained from the media service "API Access" of the Azure portal.)
[image]
[image]
However, the error is not resolved and remains.
Please let me know if there is a way to eliminate this error.

Also, the "caption" function that was displayed in the trial account cannot be used.
Is this due to the connection issue above?
I would appreciate it if you could tell me about the cause and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Azure Video Analyzer (former known as Video Indexer)
Please make sure after update connection to Azure Media Services you do not delete any secret (application key).

We found a client side issue - after update connection the error still appears (we will solve it ASAP) but after updating connection you can try refresh the page and the error won't appear.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me.  

I tried what I taught you.  
1. Update connection information  
2. Refresh the page (Shift + F5)  
The error didn't go away, but the subtitles are now available.  

If there is another solution, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.